# Составное именное сказуемое (см.)?

Tags: сказуемые, члены-предложения

При анализе одного предложения возник вопрос, связанный с определением члена предложения (что удивительно, никогда раньше не оспаривал данную конструкцию). Вот данная фраза:

"Вам — кофе, мне — чай".

Раньше всегда считал, что тире заменяет глагол-связку (как правило, "есть") при составном именном сказуемом, однако, задумавшись, понял, что слова "кофе" и "чай" все же более близки к дополнениям (например, сочетание "принести (что?) кофе"). Так всё же это именная часть или дополнение? Сам склоняюсь ко второму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Вам — кофе, мне — чай.***

Ваш пример относится к теме **неполных** предложений, но Ваш вопрос шире, чем эта тема.

**Существуют полные двусоставные предложения сходной структуры,  они называются эллиптическими предложениями.**

**Сказуемое в таких предложениях отсутствует, но подразумевается** (оно не восстанавливается по предыдущему тексту, как в неполных предложениях, а может иметь варианты).

**Примеры:**

Так вот в чём прелесть полёта в небо! Она – в паденье! 
Живучесть Чацкого – не в новизне идей (что – в чём).

Сказуемое подразумевается: *состоит, заключается и т.д.*

Смелый к победе стремится, **смелым – дорога вперёд** (**кому – что)**.

Сказуемое подразумевается: *даётся, предоставляется*.

**Также в лозунгах:**

Студентам – знания!  За первое место – приз.   Прежде всего – деловитость! Награда – победителю!  Забота о детях – прежде всего!  Родине – наш труд!

**Материал по теме:**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

Answer (score 2):

Представим диалог:

– Что Вам купить?

– Мне, пожалуйста, кофе.

– Хорошо, понял. Получается, мне [купить] – чай, Вам [купить] – кофе?

Поэтому слова "кофе" и "чай", указанные в диалоге, – дополнения, а само предложение является неполным, так как опущена грамматическая основа.

---

Если объяснение оказалось неверным или не до конца правильным, поставьте минус или напишите об этом в комментариях.